# igraph plot function does not show images in an IPython notebook

Tags: graphics, ipython, igraph

I try to do a basic igraph plotting in an IPython notebook:

```
fn = 'misrables.gml'
gr = igraph.Graph.Read_GML(fn)
igraph.plot(gr)
```

instead of seeing a graph I see this:

```
Out[7]: <igraph.drawing.Plot at 0x1120d6978>
```

How do I persuade IPython to actually show the graphics?

**Some clarifications**

Inline `matplotlib` works fine, so this is not the issue.

I have `cairo` installed:

```
import cairo
cairo.version
```

output: `1.10.0`

Calling `_repr_svg()` on the plot object results in an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/boris/Documents/workspace/communityAnalysis/src/utils.py in <module>()
----> 1 z = ig.plot(gr)._repr_svg_()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py in _repr_svg_(self)
    362         # No idea why this is needed but python crashes without
    363         context.show_page()
--> 364         surface.finish()
    365         # Return the raw SVG representation
    366         return io.getvalue()

TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the Cairo library and its Python bindings installed on your machine? The `Plot` object of igraph has a `_repr_svg_` method that should be enough for IPython to show the plot, but `_repr_svg_` uses Cairo behind the scenes to draw the graph into an SVG file, so if you don't have Cairo, `_repr_svg_` probably throws an exception that IPython swallows, and then you get an ordinary `repr()` representation for the plot.

**Update**: based on the updated post, it turned out that the problem was that `_repr_svg_` was not prepared for Python 3.x as it used a `StringIO` object where a `BytesIO` object would have been appropriate. Replacing `io = StringIO()` with `io = BytesIO()` at the beginning of the function and replacing `return io.getvalue()` with `return io.getvalue().decode()` at the end solves the problem. (`from io import BytesIO` is also needed at the top of `igraph/drawing/__init__.py`). A [bug report](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/762) has been filed on GitHub; the issue will be fixed in the next minor release.

**Update**: the issue is now fixed in the development version; see [this commit](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/037f89868190dd231f61d71ddeb3795ebc7e1274) for a patch.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have `cairo` properly installed. See my edits to the question

Comment: Can you call `_repr_svg_()` on the returned `Plot` object manually and see if you get an SVG "file" as a string in the response?

Comment: Okay, this is likely to be a Python 2.x vs Python 3.x issue; replacing `io = StringIO()` a few lines above the error in `igraph/drawing/__init__.py` with `io = BytesIO()` would probably help. (You will need to do `from io import BytesIO` at the top of `igraph/drawing/__init__.py`.

Comment: Yep, I had to change `StringIO` to `BytesIO` and have the function return `io.getvalue().decode()` instead of `io.getvalue()`. If you edit your answer I will be able to "accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

Update for igraph 0.7.1 in python 3.7.4 and IPython 7.8.0
if you install the package with:

`conda install python-igraph`

Then you can simply use

`igraph.plot(gr).show()`

and in Ubuntu a .png will be displayed automatically in a separate window with ImageMagick