# igraph plot function does not show images in jupyter notebook python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, plot, igraph, cairo, jupyter-notebook

I tried to do a single plot using Python igraph 0.6.5, cairo 1.8.8 in Ubuntu 14.04.4. This is the code:

```
import igraph as ig

G = ig.Graph.Full(10)
ig.plot(G, bbox = (400,400), layout = G.layout('kk'))
```

However, I got this message `<igraph.drawing.Plot at 0x7f1a43cc0110>` and I do not see the plot (the inline matplotlib is working). I read through this previous post [plotting issues of igraph in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887513/igraph-plot-function-does-not-show-images-in-an-ipython-notebook) but the solution seems to be for Python 3. Do you know how to proceed to see the plot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try `ig.plot(G, bbox = (400,400), layout = G.layout('kk'))._repr_svg_()` if that shows something?

Comment: @Jan Schulz it says `AttributeError: 'Plot' object has no attribute '_repr_svg_'`

Comment: It seems that this was only included in 0.7, not earlier. So you have to update. https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/commit/9cf6818ff64c2415160a32644b1a55617d7765f3 or use the code in this PR: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/36

Comment: @Jan Schulz Thanks! Updating to version 0.7 solves the problem.